# Stored procedure having issue populating record set

Tags: sql, vba, odbc, adodb

I'm having some issues with an ADODB.Recordset. I call a stored procedure that returns a password and login from the database. Once the usp is executed both the password and login are loaded into the record set. If any line of code is placed before setting the password to a string the password value reverts to Null. This doesn't with the login, only the password. Any thoughts on what I can do to fix this?

```vb
Dim objConn     As ADODB.Connection
Dim rstResult   As ADODB.recordset
Dim objCmd      As New ADODB.Command
Dim Param       As cSQLParam
Dim ParamValue  As Variant
Dim lngNumRec   As Long



Set objConn = New ADODB.Connection
objConn.Open "DSN=" & GetProfileString(gRootFolder & "InputFolder\" & "ODBC.bds", "General", "DSN")


Set objCmd = New ADODB.Command

With objCmd
    .ActiveConnection = objConn
    .CommandText = "[dbo].[usp_Credentials_GetUserCredentials]"
    .CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
    .CommandTimeout = 0
    For Each Param In Params
        .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter(Param.Name, Param.DataType, Param.Direction, Param.Size, IIf(Param.Value = "", Null, Param.Value))
    Next

End With



Set rstResult = objCmd.Execute

'any time I add code here the password shows up as Null, If no code is here the 
'correct password is displayed. Could this have to do with the password being 
'encrypted with a Salt on the server?


'Capture the password
gDataRecord.Password = rstResult("Password")

'Capture the Login
gDataRecord.Login = rstResult("LoginName")



rstResult.Close
objConn.Close
```

Comment: "any time I add code here" - like what code?  It doesn't matter if the password is encrypted (+/- salt) - whatever value the dB returns should be in the recordset.

Comment: What is `Params`?

Comment: What is `gDataRecord` (and if that `g` means "global", why on earth are you bothering with encryption if the plain-text password is right there in global scope)? ...the whole approach looks like security theater to me. Why aren't the passwords *hashed* and why would credentials even need to be anywhere in the VBA execution context?

Comment: Gdatarecord is a datastation for BWS. And I'm using this for building automations rather than macros.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue. Password was defined as a NVARCHAR(MAX), when I changed it to (255). The recordset held the variable. Thanks everyone who took a look at this.